# How to define what input should not equal within a loop?

Tags: python

Completely new to programmming and I'm having quite a few difficulties understanding loops.

I've entered the below code in Python, which tests a users knowledge of the 7 times table:

```
print('Let\'s test your knowledge of the 7 times table')
table = 7
for i in range(1, 13):
    print('What\'s', i, 'x', table, '?')
    guess = input()
    if guess == 'stop':
    break
    if guess == 'skip':
        print('Skipping. Next question:')
        continue
    ans = i * table
    if int(guess) == ans:
        print('You has teh Corrects!')
    else:
        print('Wrong, it\'s', ans)
print('Finished').')
```

I wanted to add an 'if' condition to prevent a user from inputting anything other than 'stop', 'skip' or integer input, in order to avoid the 'invalid literal for int() with base 10:' error message. I expressed this as follows:

```
if guess != int or 'stop' or 'skip':
    print('Invalid input. Please enter either a valid command or numeric response.')
    continue
```

I added this code below where the function of the 'skip' input string is defined but when I run the program now it won't recognise numeric input. I've tried inserting this after the point that it's defined that 'guess' can be an integer but at this point the loop doesn't appear to execute this part of the code as I get the 'invalid literal' error I was trying to prevent.

Apologies in advance, I know this is probably a very basic query but I've tried a number of different solutions and I'm struggling to identify whether it's my understanding of loops that's the problem or the way in which I've expressed the '!=' statement.

Thanks

Comment: Is the break properly indented?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written in the first part seems like it should work to me, if the `break` under `if guess == "stop"` be moved one tab to the right so `break` is "inside" of the `if`.

The code in the second part is wrong. You would to it like this:

```
if guess != "stop" and guess != "skip" and not guess.isdigit():
    # Do something.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.isdigit()`:

```
if not (guess.isdigit() or guess == 'stop' or guess == 'skip'):
    print('Invalid input. Please enter either a valid command or numeric response.')
    continue
```

You have to repeat the `guess` variable, that's why you probably had a syntax error. If not, it was because of the `break`'s indentation.

Comment: Apologies for late reply and thanks for the help.

The 'break' command was properly indented within the code, I must have copied it across incorrectly.

Comment: No worries, that's what I thought ;) Did you solve your problem? If so, consider accepting/upvoting the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is caused by the int(guess) itself, and not by the lack of another specific if statement. The int(guess) makes Python try to convert guess to an int and fails (returns a ValueError) if it isn't actually an integer. A way to avoid int(guess) returning an error would be to catch that exception (although I don't know if you've dealt with exceptions yet).

The way this is done is 'trying' to execute int(guess), and if it returns a ValueError, 'catching' that error:

```
try:
    if int(guess) == ans:
        print('You has teh Corrects!')
    else:
        print('Wrong, it\'s', ans)
except ValueError:
    print('Invalid input. Please enter either a valid command or numeric response.')
```